# How to order/sort a calculated field dimension in Tableau server?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a calculated field `Income`. The content of `Income` is :

```
IF return_app_account__Income < 10000
THEN "<10k"

ELSE IF return_app_account__Income < 15000
THEN "10-<15k"

ELSE IF return_app_account__Income < 30000
THEN "15-<30k"

ELSE IF return_app_account__Income < 50000
THEN "30-<50k"

ELSE IF return_app_account__Income < 100000
THEN "50-<100k"

ELSE "100k+"
END
```

`Income` is a dimension and I wanted to see percentages of total records fits in each category. I got this when I put `Income` against `Number of Records`.

[image: Income vs Number of Records]

One can see the rows are not in order i.e. `<10k` is at the bottom but it should be on top most row. I tried `sort ascending` and `sort descending` options but it does not make the rows in order. 
How to sort the rows in right order i.e `<10k` then `10-<15k` then `15-<30k` then `30-50k` then `50-<100k` then `100k+` ?

Comment: Hi Prakhar, since you are sorting a string, you probably have to either do a custom sort(you can do that in Tableau) or define your groups in a way that allows them to naturally sort the correct way. Also I don't see: "50-<100k in the results at all. Is that because there aren't any results for that sort?

Comment: @wavery Yes, the result "50-<100k" is not there because there is no record available for that. Your suggestion about defining the groups in a way that can allow the string buckets to sort automatically is helpful and I will further look into it. Can you explain a little more about custom sort ?

Comment: You can also just click and drag the `<10k` up the list to where you want it

Comment: @Andy Its not possible in my Tableau server.

Answer (score 0):

By Custom sort I mean Manual sort. If you click on the field you want to sort on in the worksheet (in this case income) and in the dropdown menu you have sort and click on it and you will get this (example):
[image: Manual Sort Example]

Comment: I cannot do this in my Tableau server. Although your suggestion of defining the string in a way that they are sorted automatically is helpful.

Comment: You probably need Tableau Desktop to do this.

Comment: Exactly my thought. But can't do that, I am working on a cloud.

Comment: You can do this on Web, it's just a bit harder .... Right-click on your calculated field and choose Default Properties > Sort.  Then choose Manual and move the values up & down to the order that you want.